# How do I make the text "og" be text, NOT part of interpreted text log

Tags: text

I'm new to LaTex and I have encountered this problem. The word "og", "and" in English. Is made part of the code and is read as log or 1og. How do I add space??

```
\textlatin{\lambda_1}=-1 og \textlatin{\lambda_2}=1 og
```

Comment: you "escape" it like when you do \& to print &.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried `\mbox{ og }`?

Comment: Is this used in a math context, e.g. inside of an `equation` environment? If so, use `\text{og}`.

Comment: Probably you want the following output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlblc.png This was created using `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\lambda_{1} = -1 \qquad\text{og}\qquad \lambda_{2} = 1
\]
\end{document}`.

Comment: @leandriis, thank you for taking your time. This is the suggestion that has helped med the most so far. How to I remove the space between math formula and text? But still get the \text{og}, to work? The math formula is part of a longer text.

Comment: I use Overleaf, (in case that is important information).

Comment: Please always provide a complete small example that shows the issue, you are asking how to change the spacing between the formula and the text but you have shown neither the text nor how you are marking up the formula.

Comment: @magn_hild: Like that? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
some text \(\lambda_{1} = -1\) og \(\lambda_{2} = 1\) other text 
\end{document}`   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLRNl.png

Comment: Thank you @leandriis! That was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you found `\textlatin`. Anyway, in LaTeX you should specifically start and end *math mode* for inline formulas:

```
we see that \(\lambda_1=-1\) and \(\lambda_2=1\) are the eigenvalues
```

Such kind of input is independent of the language used, be it English, Norwegian (Bokmål or Nynorsk), Italian or what else (even right-to-left ones).

With `\(` you *start* math mode and the whole formula must be between `\(` and the matching `\)` that ends math mode. Consider them as “words” in a foreign language.

You may find the previous input typed in like

```
we see that $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=1$ are the eigenvalues
```

where `$` is used both for starting and ending math mode.

Do yourself a favor and dedicate some time to read an introductory guide to LaTeX.  A pretty good guide is [“The not so short introduction to LaTeX”](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf). It is not available in Norwegian, I'm afraid, nor in Danish.  If you understand Danish, there is [“Introduktion til LaTeX”](https://math.medarbejdere.au.dk/latex/bog/) by [Lars Madsen (daleif)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif).